# Importing .csv file in to listview

Tags: c#

I'm trying to load a .csv file into a listview:

```
        ofDialog.Filter = @"CSV Files|*.csv";
        ofDialog.Title = @"Select your backlink file...";
        ofDialog.FileName = "backlinks.csv";

        // is cancel pressed?
        if (ofDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        try
        {
            string filename = ofDialog.FileName;
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var parts = line.Split('    ');
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(parts[0]);
                lvi.SubItems.Add(parts[1]);
                listViewMain.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
            // update count
            Helpers.returnMessage(File.ReadAllLines(ofDialog.FileName).Count() + " rows imported.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.returnMessage(ex.Message);
        }
```

The csv contents looks like:

```
    URL Rating  Domain Rating   IP From Referring Page URL  Referring Page Title    Internal Links Count    External Links Count    Link URL    TextPre Link Anchor TextPost    Size    Type    NoFollow    Site-wide   Image   Encoding    Alt First Seen  Previous Visited    Last Check  Original
    24  89  91.198.174.192  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humbug_(sweet) "Humbug (sweet) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia" 118 16  http://www.bestbritishsweets.co.uk/user/products/large/everton.jpg      http://www.bestbritishsweets.co.uk/user/products/large/everton.jpg      12163   href    True    False   False   utf8        2013-09-08T15:14:50Z    2015-03-11T01:48:40Z    2015-03-11T01:48:40Z    True
```

There is no delimeter "," like in regular .csv files, and has different spaces between some fields,  i'm stuck on the best way to split each section and add to the listview, i have a mental block lol

any help would be appreciated :)

cheers guys

Graham

Comment: Firstly: if there are no field separators it is not CSV. Second "different spaces between some fields": is it really fixed length fields? Posting an example of the format would be a good start, without which the code is largely meaningless.

Comment: Hi Richard, i posted a small example of the csv above :)

Comment: That is obviously *not CVS*. Please update the question more clearly. And then get the documentation for the format: without which you can only guess at what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

For opening the CSV file, I would first check it is not a tab separated file, where you can use `\t` as the delimiter to read the file in a similar method as you are.

Failing this you could use a (very long and complicated) regex string to match the different "columns" as different parts. The regex string would look something like:

```
\s+([0-9]*)\s+([0-9]*)\s+([0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*)\s+([a-zA-Z:\/._\(\)]*)\s+(\"[a-zA-Z0-9 \-\(\),]*\")\s+([0-9]*)\s+([0-9]*)\s+([a-zA-Z:\/._\(\)]*)\s+([a-zA-Z:\/._\(\)]*)\s+([0-9]*)\s+([a-zA-Z]*)\s+(True|False)\s+(True|False)\s+(True|False)\s+([a-z0-9]*)\s+([0-9\-T:Z]*)\s+([0-9\-T:Z]*)\s+([0-9\-T:Z]*)\s+(True|False)
```

This would return each column as a different group, which you can access as detailed below:

```
var regex = new Regex(regexString);
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var match = regex.Match(line);
    var urlRating = match.Groups[0].Value;
    var domainRating = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var ip = match.Groups[2].Value;
    // ...
}
```

You can see more about the regex string I have created (and possibly simplify it/extend it for the additional lines) here: https://regex101.com/r/oN4tW3/1

For more on C# regex look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit: I would avoid the regex method if it is tab seperated as it is more complex and fragile

Comment: Hi William, thanks for that mate :) if it was a regular , seperated file easy peasy lol but it has tab spaces and just spaces, i'll play about  abit more and post back :) thanks William.

Comment: The regex syntax of `\s+` means one or more space, so should match your input regardless of the number of spaces required to separate each variable.